# Assigning Shiny Input Variable to Gloval Environment/Data

Tags: r, shiny

I'm converting some code/script to function on a shiny server.

I need to scrape html data tables from a url, and currently, to choose the id number that changes in the url I have a function.

```
Get_ID<-function()[readline("Please choose a number:>>> ")}
num.id<-GET_ID()
```

It works quite well, it prompts to write the number in by keyboard in the console, and I can run the scrape easily for that URL identified (the value is pasted into the middle of a URL to use in further code).

I'm now trying to provide a list of numbers in a drop-down list on the ui.r file.

I have a dataframe (call it df) with these values (pre-planned url ID's)

```
NAME   number
seta   20001
setb   20002
setc   20003
setd   20004
sete   20005
```

I'd like for the 'NAME' to appear in the drop-down list and the corresponding value in "number" to be used and assigned to the variable "num.id" so that the rest of the script will execute with the current value chosen by the user.

For the ui side, I have something along the lines of:

```
selectInput("ChooseName", "df", choices=NAME), 
actionButton("submit", "SUBMIT CHOICE")
```

and I'm stuck on the server side. I've played a bit with creating an observer for the submit button, but I can't figure out a way to have the values exist in my global environment, specifically assigned to the value "num.id" - what I was using above. I would like the choice to be unique for every user. I.e., if User A chooses "setb", this won't disrupt User B who is viewing "setd".

For background, the url scrapes a table full of numbers, for which I manipulate and match to several dataframes and then output a final graph using ggplot2. Theoretically, you may recommend I pass the reactive input's from the drop-down list into the ggplot2 code directly, but there's a lot of reformatting that happens prior to use in the plot, so I'd like to keep the steps separated.

Thanks!

Comment: you can maybe try using a named list in your select input, for ex : `selectInput("numId", "Choose name",setNames(as.list(df$number),df$NAME))`. `input$numId` will then hold the number associated with the NAME, and as `input` and `output` are not shared between users there will be no interference. (some info [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping))

Comment: Thank you for the response. The setNames(as.list) certainly helps with the dataframe values. 

However, I am still having trouble passing the input$ChooseName value to my num.id (a local value that is then used in several source codes to filter tables). I have no problem keeping it as a reactive condition, proving that it 'works', but I am unable to paste the value into a global environment value.